# Removed storage/emulated/0 file and lost access to all files

Tags: internal-storage, 4.4-kitkat

I was cleaning up my files using the PC and I accidentally removed `storage/emulated/0` file completely.

I can no longer access images, music or files in general.

Is there anything I can do at this point?

Android 4.4.2, original, untouched.

The phone is a Nexus 5.

Using ES File Explorer going to `storage/emulated/0` (the `0` here is a folder) shows me and `Android` folder. This is where my data was. The `0` I removed didn't look like a folder on Windows, it looked like a file with no extension.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is a symlink (I'm on 4.1, so I can't verify). Maybe try `ln -s /sdcard /storage/emulated/0`?

Comment: `0` was a file, not a folder and it didn't look like an alias either. `/sdcard` only contains one folder: `Android`. Nothing else...

Comment: I'd expect `/storage/emulated/0` to be the actual directory containing the whole of the fake "SD card", not a symlink or a file.

Comment: Ah, that's bad news. It didn't look like a folder. And it was inside `/sdcard`. Would you say there's anything that can be done about that?

Comment: If it's a mountpoint (what I guess it is), simply re-creating the directory and then re-booting the device should fix it. If it was a symlink, re-creating the symlink should do. But you must be sure to chose the right action; i.e. if it was a symlink, and you create a directory, it won't work out. Maybe you [edit] your question and add the device you're using, so someone else with a similar configuration can check?

Comment: It's a Nexus 5. I'll update the answer and add a bit more detail about what I see using ES File Explorer. Thanks.